# DC.js pie chart of already summarized data

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter, dc

I have aggregate data like so:

```
Event  Yellows  Reds  talls  shorts
A.           1     3     5       0
B.           0     7    17      19
```

So each row contains a set of colours and a set of heights. The real data has more group fields (event is really an event type and we also have region, but I think the above simplification works)

I want to use dc.js to present two pie charts: one for colours and one for heights.

Normally using crossfilter the data would be vertical, with each row containing: event, colour, height, value. But I don't have that data; I don't have a breakdown of how many yellows were tall, for example.

I want that when you click yellow on the colours pie chart, the  height chart should only show event data where yellows>0, I.e. event A. Likewise clicking on tall would filter only where there are tall (so no filter in this dataset); click short and event A should be filtered out.

Is this possible? How?